# What is the owner in a oracle database?

Tags: oracle, database-schema, owner

When talking about relational database the concepts I've learned are that there exists schema, table, attribute. We can prefix the table name with the schema name and the attribute with the table name (even incl. schema).

When looking on an Oracle database I see things calls "OWNER".
Is this the way Oracle calls its schema, or how should I interpret them?

Best,
Will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A schema is tied to a specific Oracle user. If I create a new Oracle user, a corresponding schema is created to hold all of that user's objects.

This is why the ALL_OBJECTS table and similar tables have an OWNER field, as it designates the user that created the object, and therefore which schema it resides in.

Comment: Ok, then there is a OWNER called PUBLIC that is the schema for all users?

Comment: Public is a special user. If you want to grant privileges to all users of the database you grant them to PUBLIC.